# MotionLayout Recomposition Issue with state

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I am using MotionLayout, and I have a state that can be null.
I need to display different composables based on this state. However, I've noticed that the state doesn't trigger the recomposition of my MotionLayout, I am certain that my state has changed.
How should I adjust this?

code:

```
val userVo by LoginService.userVo.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

    MotionLayout(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize(),
        motionScene = MotionScene(content = motionJson),
        progress = toolbarState.progress
    ){
        if(userVo != null){
            ComposableA()
        }else{
            ComposableB()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your post and also include the code your LoginService class. Are you declaring `userVo` as a companion object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same issue. According to this [article](https://proandroiddev.com/debugging-the-recomposition-in-jetpack-compose-16e92cbc9c6), the trigger for recomposition occurs when updating the inputs of a composable function.

The update of `userVo` triggers a recomposition inside the `content` composable function of the `MotionLayout`. However, due to a bug, no recomposition occurs in the `MotionLayout`. This might be the reason why `MotionLayout` is still marked as `@ExperimentalMotionApi`.

My fix for the problem was to use the `key` function to force the recomposition of the `MotionLayout`:

```kotlin
key(userVo) {
    MotionLayout(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        motionScene = MotionScene(content = motionJson),
        progress = toolbarState.progress
    ) {
        if (userVo != null) {
            ComposableA()
        } else {
            ComposableB()
        }
    }
}
```